# Java full ThreadPool?

Tags: java

If I have a thread pool:

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);
```

and I start exactly 'noOfThreads' runnables.
now If I want to add another thread, how would I know that I exceeded the thead pool number of threads?

Comment: Why would you want to know? It has a queue to run the task when it can. You could find that by the time you run it, there is a free thread.

Comment: I need to know that if all threads are currently taken, to increase the number of threads! (It is obligatory in my assignment)

Comment: in that case it's not a fixed thread pool. Use a cached pool if you want it to create threads on demand.

Comment: Can't it be done at all with the fixedThreadPool?

Comment: The fixedThreadPool is the same class as the cachedThreadPool the only difference is that the fixed pool is configured with a fixed size and the cache thread pool will dynamically increase the pool size instead of queuing the tasks.

Comment: Still not what I need. I need it to remain as fixed as possible and manually do a function that shuts down and re-initializes it with the increased fixedpoolthread number.

Comment: Multi-threading is a complex topic, but this just seams like you want to make it much more complicated for no clear benefit.

Comment: Not me, no. My tutors want to make it much more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` returns an instance of type `ExecutorService`, the underlying implementation is actually an instance of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class.  You can cast to that type as follows:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor e = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);
```

You can then check if `e.getActiveCount() == e.getMaximumPoolSize()`.  If that condition is true, then you know that you don't have any threads available.

Generally though, your application shouldn't need to perform these kinds of checks.  These low-level thread pool operations are abstracted out because the component of your application that uses the `ExecutorService` should be decoupled from the thread pool internals.

Instead, you should determine appropriate settings for your thread pool when designing/developing your application, so that your threads aren't sitting in the submit queue for an unreasonable amount of time.

**Edit:**

Based on the additional details that you've provided in the comments, here's some additional information from the [`ThreadPoolExecutor` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) on how to modify the size of the thread pool after construction:

> Most typically, core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon
>   construction, but they may also be changed dynamically using
>   setCorePoolSize(int) and setMaximumPoolSize(int).

If you need additional custom behavior from your thread pool, you may be better off manually instantiating an instance of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and configuring it yourself.  (The `Executors` factory methods only provide useful preset configurations.)  See the `ThreadPoolExecutor` javadocs for details.

Comment: For a fixed thread pool, getPoolSize will always return the pool size, not the number of free threads. getPoolSize will only return 0 if there are no threads in the pool.

Comment: Thats what I just wanted to say.
I think that he means e.getActiveCount() ?

Comment: This is appropriate but is the best you can do, apart from getting the pool grow as required of course as this will avoid creating threads you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- I have fixed the condition statement.

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise, you can do this but I wouldn't suggest it.  Multi-threading is hard enough without trying to play with the thread size.

A simple way to detect you need another thread is to check the queue size.

```
 if(!tpe.getQueue().isEmpty()) {
     itn size = tpe.getCorePoolSize()+1;
     tpe.setCorePoolSize(size);
     tpe.setMaximumPoolSize(size);
 }
```